# How to condense similar duplicate jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well if my maths is right, my Jquery file is 16 times bigger than it could be.

I am building a tabbed category page which looks like this..

Tab1

- cat1
- cat2
- etc

Tab2

- cat1
- cat2
- etc

All content starts of hidden and then appears when a button in the category header is clicked (also toggling an arrow up/down).

```
$("#tabName_contentLink_cat1").click(function(){

    $("#tabName_contentLink_cat1 > .arrow").toggleClass('greyArrow_down')  
                                           .toggleClass('blackArrow_up');
    $("#tabName_content_cat1").slideToggle("fast");

});
```

This code works fine but I've repeated it 16 times!

The only part that varies is the number at the end of '_cat1'.

How can I convert this one piece of code, so that it can be reused 16 times?

I am a newbie, so please keep that in mind.

---

In my mind; assigning some sought of unique identifier (applicable category number), collecting it in a jQuery variable onClick and then pasted at the end of each _cat'HERE' seams like the way forward. I haven't a clue on how to carry it out though.

Thanks

Comment: google: `refactoring extract method`

Comment: doing that right now!

Comment: Use classes instead of ids and then relate the elements to each other via DOM traversal methods like `.find()` and `.closest()`.

Comment: you could add another class to all cat elements and make select that. That way all cat elements would have the function attached to their click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add another class to all cat elements and then use it as selector or you can do what i did. Notice i made the code smaller, efficient. And it does what you wanted by using Function.

```
addClick(cat1);
addClick(cat2);
addClick(cat3);
addClick(cat4);

function addClick(x) {
$("#tabName_contentLink_"+x).click(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle("fast").children(".arrow")
           .toggleClass('greyArrow_down blackArrow_up');
});}
```

Comment: Almost finished this, but stuck on addClick();. literally have no idea what to do with it or what it is. Is there a term for this which i can google? thanks

Comment: addclick is a function that i made. And where you were wanting to write cat1, cat2, etc. You just write 1,2,3,... in addClick(1)...You could have written 'addClick('cat1')' but i made it so you don't even have to write cat and just 1,2,3,...

Comment: Your syntax looks great, but I'm still having problems implementing it. What do you think about this fiddle?http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/7cVwe/4/

Comment: 1st you don't have jquery on...at left side. And 2nd there is no element with **id** `#tabName_contentLink_cat1` that is visible...how about this tell me what you are trying to do.

Comment: oops.. thing is, i've fixed this and it's still not working http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/7cVwe/5/

Comment: I put in two example tabs, but i don't see how addClick(#) communicates with the html... and differiantiates between each tab, as their are no visible selectors assigned to each addClick?

Comment: right! I think i fixed a few misplaced id's, here is another updated revision http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/7cVwe/6/ ..still not working though -.-

Comment: check out the version i made... is this what you wanted to do. I am bad at understanding other's code...http://jsfiddle.net/7cVwe/7/        ....made it cleaner

Comment: This is spot on! Thanks alot

Comment: though in css i haven't include no user select, cursor, and other browsers beside webkit..you can just add that by replacing webkit with moz etc...

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$("[id^='tabName_contentLink_cat']").click(function(){

  $(this).children(".arrow").toggleClass('greyArrow_down')  
                            .toggleClass('blackArrow_up');

  var contentId = this.id.replace(/contentLink/, 'content');
  $("#"+ contentId).slideToggle("fast");

});
```

It's not the most elegant code, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Give them all the `tabName_contentLink` class, then:

```
$(".tabName_contentLink").click(function(){

    $(this).children(".arrow").toggleClass('greyArrow_down')
        .toggleClass('blackArrow_up');
    $(this).find(".tabName_content").slideToggle("fast");

});
```

The keyword `this` allows you to reference the object calling the function, thus relate to a specific object out of a set. It can become a little tricky, but basically - you can use it as described above.

Comment: Did you notice that the `.slideToggle()` isn't on the same element as the `.click()`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple for loop?

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 16; i++){
  $("#tabName_contentLink_cat" + i).click(function(){

      $("#tabName_contentLink_cat" + i + " > .arrow").toggleClass('greyArrow_down')  
                                             .toggleClass('blackArrow_up');
      $("#tabName_content_cat" + 1).slideToggle("fast");

  });
}
```

There are other options, but this seems to be the quickest way to make it work without changing too much of the existing code. To make it more generic you can wrap it in a function that receives 'i' as an argument.